# Old Film developement

Tags: printing

For the Person that had film processed after 20 years. Where did you get the special processing done? Also I have some undeveloped close to 20 years old and need to know the best place to get it developed to try and get something out of it.

Comment: When asking "where" questions you ought to at least say where *you* are roughly.  A country would be the minimum to tell  people.

Comment: @StephenG such recommendations are off topic to begin with, and too localized as well.

Comment: @micheal-clark I agree with you, of course, but was commenting for the OP's general info when using the internet.  It's surprising how many people post questions like these on forums and just assume everyone will know where they're from.

Comment: You should be aware that there is (gosh) a **search engine** for this site that will let you find the previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

Contact the Darkroom - they specialize in old film developing and printing.
https://thedarkroom.com/old-rolls-film-developing/